# simple Update from a select statement is stuck running

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am running the query below, where I am just getting a bunch of IDs that I want to use in an update statement, and then use to update

```
SET sql_safe_updates=0;
create temporary table nullmeters
    select me.id from met me
    join  tab1 ac on ac.accounts_id = me.id
    join tab2 po on ac.val1 = po.id
    join tab3 te on te.id = me.team_id
    where
    me.name = 'NULL';

select * from nullmeters;

update tab1 set deleted = 1 where id in (
select id from nullmeters
);

update met set deleted = 1 where id in (
select id from nullmeters
);

drop temporary table nullmeters;
```

When I run this, it looks to get stuck running and not move on in the update statement. It looks like it gets stuck when trying to update using the ids selected from the temp table. The select is all good and the temp table holds all the ids from the query

If I run the update statements, but with the actual values i.e

update tab1 set deleted = 1 where accounts in (
'1',
'2'
);

update met set deleted = 1 where id in (
'1',
'2'
);

It works okay.

Comment: Does `update tab1 set deleted = 1 where exists (select 1 from nullmeters where id = tab1.id);` make any difference? If not, does `update tab1 set deleted = 1 where exists (
select 1 from met me join tab1 ac on ac.accounts_sms_meters_1sms_meters_idb = me.id join tab2 po ... where me.name = 'NULL' and me.id = tab1.id );` run faster for you?

Comment: Thanks for the update, still look to do the same, running this on workbench, wonder if just stuck or not

Comment: You might want to try adding some indexes starting with me.name. Also check whether me.name is the string `'NULL'` or no data (null). If no data, then you want to write me.name is null. Also, ensuring there's index on ac.accounts_id, me.id, ac.val1, po.id, and te.id may also help. Try adding a couple indexes.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL often optimizes `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)` poorly. It works much better with a join:

```
UPDATE tab1 AS t
JOIN nullmeters AS n ON t.id = n.id
SET t1.deleted = 1;
```

Also, you should add an index on the `id` column of `nullmeters`.

```
ALTER TABLE nullmeters ADD INDEX (id);
```

Comment: Thanks you, yes using the join has made the difference, can see the in clause was the issue. This looks to have run well now., many thanks again